# scraping google search results via rvest

Tags: r, for-loop, url, web-scraping, rvest

I have a data frame like so:

```
library(rvest)
library(urltools)
library(tm)

names <- ("bloomberg", "wilson athletics", "houston rockets", "gap inc")
website1 <- "NA"
website2 <- "NA"

df <- data.frame(names, website1, website2)
```

The following code gives the first 2 url from a google search with name as a search term:

```
for(name in df$name[1:4]){
  print(paste0("finding the url for:", name))
  Sys.sleep(20)

  url = URLencode(paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=", name))
  page1 <- read_html(url)
  results <- page1 %>% html_nodes("cite") %>% html_text()
  result1 <- as.character(results[1])
  df[df$name == name,]$website1 <- result1
  result2 <- as.character(results[2])
  df[df$name == name,]$website2 <- result2
}
```

My question is:

1. How do I generalize the above to, say, the first 10 urls without explicitly typing out `df$website1...df$website10` in the above loop?  I know I can create the variables using the following:

   `sites <- paste("website", 1:10, sep = ".")
   na_vector <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
        for(s in sites) {
         df[[s]] <- na_vector
   }`

But I am unsure of how to incorporate that into the above loop efficiently. 
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a violation of Google's ToS and despite recent U.S. 9th Circuit rulings could result in civil penalties for U.S. citizens and both civil and criminal penalties for those in other jurisdictions (& said 9th Circuit rulings could be overturned with pending cases on various dockets in the U.S. in 2018). Anyone who helps is potentially subject to these very real legal issues and should know that before helping.

Comment: Google itself is a scraper

Comment: Yes. And most ToS let them and others like them do it. You're definitely not google. But props for trying to build an argument for criminal activity.

Comment: No, i am not google.  I'm just a guy trying to improve his skills and knowledge by interacting with other ppl who can provide insight.  There's no need to be rude.  There's no need to be snarky.  I didn't do anything to you.  Sheesh.

Comment: What is "snarky" or rude about @hrbrmstr's advice? From where I sit, it appears to be quite helpful, and advice you should strongly consider following.

Comment: I wasn't trying to build an argument for criminal activity.  That was incredibly rude.  I am not a criminal.  It was useful advice yes but why tell me i am trying to rationalize criminal activity? Was that necessary?

Comment: Because I noted that the activity has a non-0 likelihood of causing criminal or civil penalties & you completely dismissed it or tried to justify it. That's why. You chose to persist via your defense despite now knowing the potential issues. Depending on the jurisdiction, the reply became defense of criminal activity. LinkedIn & others sued orgs successfully in 2017; a U.S. 9th Circuit court upheld civil penalties for ToS violations (but negated criminal ones). There are 2 cases this yr that cld re-validate criminal penalties & also make it much easier for orgs to take even 1 person to court.

Comment: @hrbrmstr relevant: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2019/09/victory-ruling-hiq-v-linkedin-protects-scraping-public-data .